# Корректировка в файле С++?

Tags: c++

Как заменить содержимое строки файла, если в каждой строке находится целочисленное значение.

Answer (score 1):

1. Его можно полностью считать в массив и уже работать с элементами массива, затем перезаписать этот файл, выведя в него элементы массива.
2. Открыть файл на чтение и запись (append), найти и изменить данные в нужной строке.

Comment: Только при update (не перезапись) файла надо следить, чтобы длины строк не менялись.